# How to avoid creating duplicated footnotes?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am parsing an XML that has two footnotes pointing to the same source, as in reference [1] in this example:

[image]

This is my parsing code:

```xml
<xsl:template match="//sup[@class='reference']/a">
    <xsl:variable name="cite_number">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(./text(),']'),'[')"/> <!-- to remove the [ ] characters -->
    </xsl:variable>
    <fo:footnote>
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><fo:inline font-size="6pt" vertical-align="super"><xsl:value-of select="$cite_number"/></fo:inline></fo:inline>
        <fo:footnote-body>
            <xsl:variable name="cite_id"> <!-- variable to find the content of the cite -->
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@href,'#')"/> <!-- to remove the # character -->
            </xsl:variable>
            <fo:block color="#999999">
                <xsl:value-of select="$cite_number"/>
                <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::subchapter[@lang]//li[@id=$cite_id]/span[@class='reference-text']"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:footnote-body>
    </fo:footnote>
</xsl:template>
```

The variable `cite_number` is the number of the cite (1, 2, 3, etc.). If there are two cites pointing at the same source, as shown in the image, the footnote is created twice.

What would be the way of having only one footnote for multiple repeated cites?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding a conditional that prints either the full footnote or just the superindex. In my case, which is MediaWiki pages, I check the `id` attribute of the parent to determine if there is only one instance of the cite `not(contains(../@id,':'))` or if there are more than one, and then look for the first one `(contains(../@id,'-0'))`:

```xml
<xsl:template match="//sup[@class='reference']/a">
    <xsl:variable name="cite_number">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(./text(),']'),'[')"/> <!-- to remove the [ ] characters -->
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains(../@id,':')) or (contains(../@id,'-0'))]">
            <fo:footnote>
                <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><fo:inline font-size="6pt" vertical-align="super"><xsl:value-of select="$cite_number"/></fo:inline></fo:inline>
                <fo:footnote-body>
                    <!-- footnote-body here -->
                </fo:footnote-body>
            </fo:footnote>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><fo:inline font-size="6pt" vertical-align="super"><xsl:value-of select="$cite_number"/></fo:inline></fo:inline>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```